# How can I add a tittle to a barplot in R?

Tags: r

How can I add a tittle to this barplot in R? I would like to add a tittle to this barplot but I don't know where to put it in this code.

```
barplot(sort(table(BartRider$DualInc), decreasing = TRUE))
```

Comment: Use the `main` option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the `main` parameter of `barplot()` and specify your title there, i.e.

```
barplot(sort(table(BartRider$DualInc), decreasing=TRUE),
        main="Your title goes here")
```

Another option would be to use the `title()` function *after* your call to `barplot()`:

```
title(main="Your title goes here", sub="sub-title",
      xlab="x-axis label", ylab="y-axis label")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `main` argument in `barplot`

```
barplot(sort(table(BartRider$DualInc), decreasing = TRUE), main = "Bar plot XYZ")
```